# Différence entre cotisations « non payées » et « impayées » ?

Tags: sens, usage, adjectifs, participe-passé, synonymes

En lisant que des pays n'ont pas payé les cotisations qu'ils devaient à l'[UNESCO](https://fr.unesco.org/), qu'ils viennent formellement de quitter d'après ce que j'en comprends parce qu'ils étaient incapables de la manipuler ou de la censurer (comme c'est le cas de plus en plus pour eux avec d'autres institutions des Nations Unies d'ailleurs), je trouve le passage suivant :

> Depuis lors, les responsables estiment que les États-Unis - qui
>   contribuaient pour environ 22 % du budget total de l'UNESCO - ont
>   accumulé 600 millions US en cotisations **non payées** ; Israël
>   devrait environ 10 millions.
>
> [ « [Les États-Unis et Israël ont quitté l'UNESCO](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/201901/02/01-5209772-les-etats-unis-et-israel-ont-quitte-lunesco.php) » ds. La Presse via
>   AP ]

- Y a-t-il une différence de sens, d'usage ou de fréquence d'emploi entre *non [payé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/payer)* et [*impayé*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/impay%C3%A9) ; sont-ils parfaitement interchangeables dans tous les contextes, incluant celui de l'extrait ?

Answer (score 5):

Comme la définition de l'adjectif « impayé » dans le TLFi est précisément « non payé » il ne faut pas chercher plus loin : les deux termes sont exactement équivalents.

Dans un contexte de substantivation de « impayé », l'équivalence n'est plus valide ; si j'ai assez souvent entendu parler des « impayés » je n'ai jamais entendu dire ou vu à l'écrit  « non payés ». On utilise le substantif « impayé » dans le commerce.

Comment: Bien sûr que si il faut aller chercher plus loin quand on veut affirmer comme vous le faites, une "exacte équivalence". Avant d'affirmer ce genre de chose, il faut chercher à vérifier la validité de la réciproque. Et comme, dans ce cas précis, la réciproque n'est pas toujours vraie, on ne peut pas parler d'équivalence.

Comment: @aCOSwt Quelques cas d'illustration seraient grandement les bienvenus.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Ce étant dit que je ne connais rien aux conditions d'adhésion à l'UNESCO ni aux engagements des états membres ni aux conditions de démission et que je ne saurais par conséquent pas assurer que la nuance développée ici peut valoir dans ce cas précis.</sub>

Ha! Des cotisations! Mais ça change tout ça!

Je ne le réalise que ce matin en lisant dans la presse qu'Alain Juppé ( Un ancien prof à l'UQAM ;-) ) n'a pas payé sa cotisation de membre d'un parti politique.

Je pense que, à titre de particulier, on peut vouloir faire la différence entre ce qui est un **dû** (une facture d'un fournisseur) échangé contre un service, un bien dont on profite et ce qui est une **contribution** (dons à des associations, denier du culte, étrennes du facteur...) effectuée à titre (plus ou moins) gratuit.

Dans le premier cas, on *paye* au sens propre du terme. Sinon, la facture peut conséquemment être justement dite *impayée*.

Dans le second cas, on ne *paye* pas au sens propre du terme. On donne. Et très souvent ce que l'on veut et quand on veut. Et si on ne donne pas tant, ici et maintenant, Il n'y a par conséquent aucune substance qui puisse justifier ce qualificatif d'impayé au sens du TLF.

Peut-être préférerais-je dire dans ce cas *non-acquitté, non-versé ou non-honoré*...

Mais il se trouve que, clin d’œil de l'étymologie, facétie linguistique ou, moins prosaïquement indigence lexicale, le vulgus utilise de plus en plus le verbe *payer* dès qu'il sort son porte-monnaie. Dès qu'il... débourse... de l'argent, en général et quelle qu'en soit la cause.

Et le voilà parti... bien improprement... **payer** sa cottise, le denier du culte et son pari sportif comme il payerait ses impôts, son loyer et sa place pour le prochain PSG / MU.

Le sens de l'adjectif *impayé* ne s'étant pas étendu identiquement, les *non-dons*, les *non-contributions-spontanées* ne le méritent assurément pas.
Reste alors le secours de la linguistique qui, et quel que soit le sens que je donne à *payer*, m'autorisera à qualifier de *payé* ce qui l'est et de *non-payé* ce qui ne l'est pas.

<sub>NDaCOSwt : En tous les cas, donc, et contrairement à ce qu'affirme une autre réponse, **il n'y a aucune sorte d'*équivalence* entre *non-payé* et *impayé*** puisque si *impayé* signifie toujours *non-payé*, *non-payé* ne signifie pas toujours *impayé*. Pas de réciproque donc pas d'équivalence.</sub>

Comment: Si dans le second cas on ne paye pas au sens propre du terme, ce avec quoi je ne peut qu'être d'accord, et que donc il ne peut pas être question d'impayé, il ne peut pas non plus être question de « non payé ». Que nous importe des notions d'équivalence dans ce cas ? Bien que vos remarques philosophiques ne manque pas d'intérêt elles ne concernent pas cette question comparativement terre à terre qui nous occupe.

Comment: De plus je suis très surpris ce votre manière de considérer une définition de dictionnaire, dont la  logique veut qu'elle soit strictement interchangeable avec le terme qu'elle détermine; cette logique est une nécessité incontournable selon mon point de vue.